# How to write an Android Method that displays 3 columns of same row in 3 different textviews?

Tags: java, android, database

I'm new to Android. I'm trying to write a single method that would display 3 different columns from the same row of a database in 3 different textviews. Right now, I have 3 identical methods that each display a different column from the same row:

```
        Display part of Method #1:
if (cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = result
        + cursor.getString(0);
        return result;
    }
    return null;


    Display part of Method #2:
if (cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = result
        + cursor.getString(1);
        return result;
    }
    return null;

    Display part of Method #3:
if (cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = result
        + cursor.getString(2);
        return result;
    }
    return null;
```

So my question is: Is there a way to write a single method where the result would be something like "for a single DB row, cursor.getString(0); display in TextView #1, cursor.getString(1); display in TextView #2, cursor.getString(2); display in TextView #3?"

Comment: Your code has redundancy problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (cursor != null){
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String string1 = cursor.getString(0);
    .... string2 = cursor.getString(1);
    .... string3 = cursor.getString(2);
    textView1.setText(string1);
    textView2.setText(string2);
    textView3.setText(string3);
}
```

In case of Database Adapter, you can do one thing

```
if (cursor != null){
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String strings[] = new String[3];
    strings[0] = cursor.getString(0);
    strings[1] = cursor.getString(1);
    strings[2] = cursor.getString(2);
    return strings;
```

In the calling activity you can set these returned array elements to textviews easily.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that would be a way of doing it, but the method I'm trying to write is in my Database Adapter Activity, and I'm calling the method from another Activity. So the method (in the DB Adapter Activity) can't see the textViews calls because they're in another Activity. How can I get the DB Adapter Activity to see the textviews?

Answer (score 0):

Use a string builder and the "\n" character in the TextView. or just have 3 TextViews.